# Adaptable UICollectionViewCell Background image - locked/unlocked game levels

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, nsarray, uicollectionviewcell

I have very little experience working with `UICollectionView`'s but I've managed to create a scrollable interface that displays 100 buttons for 100 levels, 4 across, 25 down (well, they get generated on-the-fly as you know).  The type of level is called `Tortoise` just so you're wondering what the hell that stands for later on.  For `Tortoise`, there are only 20 levels.

Right now, the cell data string that I use to display the number gets placed over a regular background for the cell (indicating the level has been unlocked but not completed).

I have 2 other images I'd like to use as background images (one is a lock image where no number string appears, and the other is the same background as above just with a small checkmark for completion (along with the number string on top)).

To brief you, I'm using Core Data to keep track of a couple set of objects, along with whether a level is locked or unlocked.  I call a method (right as I enter my Tortoise UICollectionView) called `figureOutLocks` which stores either a 0, 1, or 2 `NSNumber` object in this array `self.lockArray`.  Here's that method:

```
    - (void)figureOutLocks {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                                                                    delegate] managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Score" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %d AND %K == %d",
                                       @"level", i, @"typeOfLevel", 0];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
            NSError *error = nil;
            Score* lockInfo = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                     error:&error] lastObject];

            lockInfo.levelCompleted = [lockInfo valueForKey:@"levelCompleted"];
            lockInfo.lockedLevel = [lockInfo valueForKey:@"lockedLevel"];
            NSInteger complete = [lockInfo.levelCompleted integerValue];
            NSInteger locked = [lockInfo.lockedLevel integerValue];

            if ((locked == 0) && (complete == 0)) {
                // level is unlocked but not complete (does not have any saved scores)
                // lockArray gets a 0
                [self.lockArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
            } else if ((locked == 1) && (complete == 0)) {
                // level is locked which implies it is not complete
                // lockArray gets a 1
                [self.lockArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];
            } else if ((locked == 0) && (complete == 1)) {
                // level is complete thus it is unlocked
                // lockArray gets a 2
                [self.lockArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]];
            }
        }
    }
```

To brief you again, the first level is unlocked and not completed, and the other levels are locked (thus not completed).

Also, I created a `NSArray *dataArray` that contains string objects 1-20, and a `NSArray *compareArray` that contains `NSNumber` objects 1-20. My `lockArray` is `NSMutableArray`.

Furthermore, I decided to make 2 separate `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses in order to use both the regular background and the locked background. I didn't add the completion background subclass because I wanted to make sure the locked background works.

Here's the main method:

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UICollectionViewCell *regular;

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"tortoiseCell";
        static NSString *tortIdentifier = @"tortoiseLocked";
        TortoiseCell *cell = (TortoiseCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        TortoiseLocked *lockCell = (TortoiseLocked *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:tortIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSMutableArray *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSMutableArray *locks = [self.compareArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSNumber *locksData = [locks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSInteger locked = [locksData integerValue];
        NSInteger lock = [[self.lockArray objectAtIndex:locked] integerValue];

        if (lock == 0) {
           [cell.buttonClick setTag:indexPath.row];
           [cell.buttonClick setTitle:cellData forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [cell.buttonClick setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TortoiseLevels.png"]
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [cell.buttonClick setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [cell.buttonClick.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:25]];
           [cell.buttonClick addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedSoWhatNumber:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           cell.buttonClick.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
           cell.buttonClick.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
           [cell addSubview:cell.buttonClick];
           cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
           cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
           regular = cell;
        } else if (lock == 1) {
           [lockCell.tortoiseLock setTag:indexPath.row];
           [lockCell.tortoiseLock setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TortoiseLock.png"]
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           lockCell.tortoiseLock.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
           lockCell.tortoiseLock.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
           [lockCell addSubview:lockCell.tortoiseLock];
           lockCell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
           lockCell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
           regular = lockCell;
        }

        return regular;
    }
```

Is what I've done even possible?  How do I make this work if it is?  I tried using one `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and just programmatically change backgrounds but that didn't work, that's why you see what you see with the larger `if` statements.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't need to dequeue *both* cells from the table - you'll only ever be using one of them. Your code should be structured more like this:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"tortoiseCell";
static NSString *tortIdentifier = @"tortoiseLocked";

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *regular;

    NSMutableArray *locks = [self.compareArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSNumber *locksData = [locks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger locked = [locksData integerValue];

    NSMutableArray *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger lock = [[self.lockArray objectAtIndex:locked] integerValue];

    if (lock == 0) {

        TortoiseCell *cell = (TortoiseCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.buttonClick setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell.buttonClick setTitle:cellData forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonClick setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TortoiseLevels.png"]
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonClick setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonClick.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:25]];
        [cell.buttonClick addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedSoWhatNumber:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.buttonClick.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        cell.buttonClick.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [cell addSubview:cell.buttonClick];
        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        regular = cell;

    } else if (lock == 1) {

        TortoiseLocked *lockCell = (TortoiseLocked *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:tortIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [lockCell.tortoiseLock setTag:indexPath.row];
        [lockCell.tortoiseLock setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TortoiseLock.png"]
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        lockCell.tortoiseLock.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        lockCell.tortoiseLock.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [lockCell addSubview:lockCell.tortoiseLock];
        lockCell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        lockCell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        regular = lockCell;
    }

    return regular;
}
```

Also, since you have already set up two types of cell prototype on the storyboard, why bother setting each cell up programmatically? Just make them look how you want on the storyboard, and add the level number in the code.

Comment: Great solution.  Also turns out my process of using one of the objects of my `compareArray` to evaluate a value of an object in `lockArray` was very wrong.  And when all of my work is done, I'll try to convert it all via the nib and storyboard.  I just like to see the code all laid out since I'm very new to it all still